How to use GoemansWilliamsonOptimizer from qiskit_optimization.algorithms?
I have created a big instance of a max cut problem, which is in a QuadraticProgram. Now when I try to do this:
from qiskit_optimization.algorithms import GoemansWilliamsonOptimizer

optimizer = GoemansWilliamsonOptimizer(num_cuts=1)
optimizer.solve(problem_max_cut)


It gives me the error that : LinAlgError: 0-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional
No matter whatever value I set for the num_cuts, it gives me the same error.
I have tried checking whether the problem is compatible with the method or not, using
optimizer.is_compatible(problem_max_cut)

and it always returns True.
How to make use of it?
